Búsqueda de datos en una tabla en vivo
Estoy realizando un buscador para una simple tabla, que me lista todos los usuarios de mi base de datos, se va agrandando cada vez mas, y bueno se hace largo la búsqueda a veces, entonces me puse a hacer el buscador, como no se mucho de JS lo busque en Internet, y lo acople a PHP. Funciona a medias.. ya que me trae los datos incompletos, por alguna razón no trae el ID 1. Empieza desde el ID 2, son 31 usuario por ahora., y luego al escribir en el buscador, hace la búsqueda de una manera muy rara. Mas que seguro no estoy comprendiendo como aplicar la búsqueda. Por eso escribo acá, para ver si alguien puede ayudarme a ver lo que esta mal.
Código:
HTML:
<div>
  <label for="caja_busqueda">Buscar:</label>
     <input type="text" name="caja_busqueda" id="caja_busqueda"></input>
</div>
<div id="datos"></div> <!-- TABLA USUARIOS -->

JS:
$(buscar_datos());

function buscar_datos(consulta) {
   $.ajax({
    url: 'buscar.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {consulta: consulta},
 })
 .done(function(respuesta) {
    $("#datos").html(respuesta);
 })
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
   })
 }

$(document).on('keyup', '#caja_busqueda', function(){
var valor = $(this).val();
if(valor != ""){
    buscar_datos(valor);
} else {
    buscar_datos();
}
});

PHP:
 $salida = "";
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios ";

if(isset($_POST['consulta'])){

  $q = $_POST['consulta'];

 $query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE Usuario LIKE '%".$q."%' OR Nom_y_Ape LIKE '%".$q."%'";

}
$resultado = mysqli_query( $conn, $query );

if ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado )) {

$salida.= "<table class=\"table-principal\" method=\"POST\">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope=\"col\">USUARIO</th>
                    <th scope=\"col\">ID RED</th>
                    <th scope=\"col\">GRUPO/PERMISO</th>
                    <th scope=\"col\">ACCESO A</th>
                    <th scope=\"col\">NOC</th>
                    <th scope=\"col\">RDLS</th>
                    <th scope=\"col\">PH</th>
                    <th scope=\"col\">RIO</th>
                    <th scope=\"col\">AND</th>
                    <th scope=\"col\">BARROSA</th>
                    <th scope=\"col\">EFO</th>
                    <th scope=\"col\">LLL</th>
                    <th scope=\"col\">PL ARENAS</th>
                    <th scope=\"col\">MODIFICACIONES</th>
                    <th scope=\"col\">ELIMINAR USUARIO</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>";

        while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ) ){

        $salida.= " <tr class=\"tr\">
                        <td style=\"display: none\">".$fila[ 0 ]."</td>
                        <td>".$fila[ 4 ]."</td> 
                        <td>".$fila[ 2 ]."</td>
                        <td>".str_ireplace($admin_regular, $admin_nueva, $fila[ 1 ])."</td>
                        <td>".str_ireplace($acceso_regular, $acceso_nuevo, $fila[ 3 ])."</td>
                        <td>".$fila[5]."</td>
                        <td>".$fila[6]."</td>
                        <td>".$fila[7]."</td>
                        <td>".$fila[8]."</td>
                        <td>".$fila[9]."</td>
                        <td>".$fila[10]."</td>
                        <td>".$fila[11]."</td>
                        <td>".$fila[12]."</td>
                        <td>".$fila[13]."</td> 
                    </tr>";
    }

    $salida.="</tbody></table>";

 } else {
    $salida.="<p>DATO NO ENCONTRADO</p>";
}

echo $salida;

Si alguien pudiera orientarme en que esta mal? porque le estoy dando vueltas, verificando que este todo bien, y no logro encontrar la falla.

Como se ha explicado en la respuesta, los métodos fetch_ se colocan en la siguiente fila cada vez que son llamados, precisamente por eso se suelen vaciar dentro de un bucle while, que leerá las filas una por una y saldrá cuando el puntero de datos esté vacío. Por otra parte, no deberías confiar en num_rows para saber si hay filas, porque depende del buffer y PHP se puede otorgar la libertad de no meter determinados resultados en el buffer, porque no tiene memoria en ese momento o por lo que sea ... Por eso es mejor siempre ¡verificar los mismos datos para saber si hay datos!

... Para ello puedes declarar un array vacío antes del while, y fuera del while verificar si el array sigue o no vacío. En casos donde sólo se quiere verificar si hay filas para decidir una acción, lo mejor es usar una consulta del tipo SELECT COUNT(*) ..., pero esto no creo que venga al caso para este código. Para una demostración sobre lo del buffer, puedes ver esta respuesta.

Estás llamando 2 veces mysql_fetch_array antes y después del bucle (esto hace que te saltes el primer registro), reemplaza el que está antes del bucle:
if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0) { ... }

suponiendo que estás usando esa condición para validar que retorne filas.

Vaya, tanto código que uno empieza a marearse. Es justamente ese el error.! Muy amable por la respuesta! Muy agradecido!

No hay de que, un placer ayudarte!
